# Why PKCS#7 always requires padding even if the data length is multiple of the block size

Tags: c++, cryptography

I just discovered that my PKCS#5 isn't compliant with the standard as in my implementation padding is not added if the data length is multiple of block size except when all last block bytes equal to the block size (the last block is like a padding block). I saw that the standard behavior is to add a padding block of size of block size when the data size is multiple of block length no matter the last block content.

I'm confused because my implementation was just working and saved extra padding when the size of data was aligned, so why this requirement in the standard ?

this is some test code on aes block size (16 bytes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

template<size_t block_length>
inline size_t calc_existing_padding_size(const uint8_t* buff, size_t size)
{
    assert(size && size % block_length == 0);

    uint8_t last_byte = buff[size - 1];
    if (last_byte > block_length || !last_byte)
        return 0;

    auto end = buff + size;
    auto start = end - last_byte;

    while (start != end)
    {
        if (*start != last_byte)
            return 0;
        ++start;
    }

    return last_byte;
}

template<size_t block_length>
inline size_t calc_required_padding_size(const uint8_t* buff, size_t size)
{
    assert(buff && size);

    if (size < block_length)
        return block_length - size;

    if ((size == block_length) || (size % block_length == 0))
    {
        if (calc_existing_padding_size<block_length>(buff, size))
            return block_length;
        return 0;
    }

    return block_length - (size % block_length);
}

template<size_t block_length>
void add_padding(std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
{
    auto padding_size = calc_required_padding_size<block_length>(data.data(), data.size());
    data.resize(padding_size + data.size(), static_cast<uint8_t>(padding_size));
}

template<size_t block_length>
void remove_padding(std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
{
     auto padding_size = calc_existing_padding_size<block_length>(data.data(), data.size());
     data.resize(data.size() - padding_size);
}

struct test_entry
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    std::vector<uint8_t> padded_data;
    std::vector<uint8_t> unpadded_data;

    test_entry(std::vector<uint8_t> test_data, std::vector<uint8_t> after_padding) 
    : data(std::move(test_data)), padded_data(std::move(after_padding))
    {
        unpadded_data = data;

    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t block_length = 16;

    std::vector<test_entry> tests;

    auto make_test_entry = [](size_t data_size, uint8_t fill_byte)
    {
        assert(data_size <= block_length);

        std::vector<uint8_t> data(data_size, fill_byte);
        std::vector<uint8_t> padded_data = data;
        padded_data.resize(block_length, static_cast<uint8_t>(block_length - data_size ));
        return test_entry(std::move(data), std::move(padded_data));
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < block_length - 1; ++i)
    {
        tests.emplace_back(make_test_entry(i + 1, static_cast<uint8_t>(i + 1)));
    }

    tests.emplace_back(make_test_entry(block_length, '5'));

    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> data(block_length, static_cast<uint8_t>(block_length));
        auto padded_data = data;
        padded_data.resize(padded_data.size() + block_length, static_cast<uint8_t>(block_length));
        tests.emplace_back(std::move(data), std::move(padded_data));
    }

    std::cout << "[*] performing " << tests.size() << " tests" << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < tests.size(); ++i)
    {

        add_padding<block_length>(tests[i].data);
        
        if (tests[i].data.size() != tests[i].padded_data.size()
        || ! std::equal(tests[i].data.begin(), tests[i].data.end(), tests[i].padded_data.begin()))
        {
            std::cout << "[!] test [" << i << "] failed in adding padding !" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        remove_padding<block_length>(tests[i].data);
        
        if (tests[i].data.size() != tests[i].unpadded_data.size()
        || ! std::equal(tests[i].data.begin(), tests[i].data.end(), tests[i].unpadded_data.begin()))
        {
            std::cout << "[!] test [" << i << "] failed in removing padding !" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "[*] test [" << i << "] passed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: When trying to decrypt the code would not know if there was padding or not.

Comment: no, it can be determined using the result size and the last block

Comment: The block size is fixed and is decrypted without knowing the message details.  So is the last 5 bytes (say) padding to be removed or data to be returned?

Comment: edited the code to reflect my real implementation. if the size is aligned and the last block is similar to a padding block then a full padding block is appended otherwise no. so when encrypting if the plaintext ends with 5 bytes equal to 0x5, then a padding block of 16 bytes is appended so that it is removed by the decryptor

Comment: PKCS#7 assumes no knowledge of the plaintext. Having it encrypt to a certain number of bytes and then add an additional block once in a while is a tricky proposition - you cannot really depend on the ciphertext size to be smaller after all. Besides that it would be hard to calculate the ciphertext size in advance. But yeah, in principle above could work. Not that we care, more cryptographers have moved on to CTR which doesn't pad at all. Most authenticated ciphers use CTR mode underneath.

Comment: Anyway I have to move to standard PKCS#7 to support other implementations which assumes this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> This is necessary so the deciphering algorithm can determine with
> certainty whether the last byte of the last block is a pad byte
> indicating the number of padding bytes added or part of the plaintext
> message. Consider a plaintext message that is an integer multiple of B
> bytes with the last byte of plaintext being 01. With no additional
> information, the deciphering algorithm will not be able to determine
> whether the last byte is a plaintext byte or a pad byte. However, by
> adding B bytes each of value B after the 01 plaintext byte, the
> deciphering algorithm can always treat the last byte as a pad byte and
> strip the appropriate number of pad bytes off the end of the
> ciphertext; said number of bytes to be stripped based on the value of
> the last byte. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)

If you know the message will always be a multiple of the block size, you can likely specify the cipher to not apply padding, or use a cipher mode, as mentioned in the comments, that doesn't require padding.